# Understanding PHP's OOP magic methods __set() and __get()

Tags: php, oop

I am having difficulty understanding the magic methods in object oriented PHP - for example, `__set()`:

```
<?php
class Post{
    private $name;

    public function __set($name, $value){
        echo 'Setting '.$name.' to <strong>'.$value.'</strong><br />';
        $this->name = $value;
    }
}

$post = new Post;
$post->name = 'Testing';
?>
```

This prints out:

> Setting name to Testing

What I am not understanding is why did `$name` change to "name" inside `__set()`?

I would also like some explanation in plain English on how and why to use `__set()` and `__get()`.

Comment: If you would call `$post->it = "now"` then `$name` will have the value of `it`. The first parameter for `__set` is the property name, the second its assigned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$name` changed to `$this->name`, not to `name`. In `$this->name` it is a property of object `$this`.

Normally you would never use `__get()` and `__set()`. They can be used, for instance, in error handling to get access to an inaccessable or `private` properties, like your `name` property.

Comment: so i understand why we use __set(), but what really i didn't get is why `$name` in line 6 changes to "name"_  in the output

Comment: `$name` is a parameter of method `__set()` whereas `$this->name` is a private property of class `Post`. Two different things altogether. Basic concepts. See for instance: http://phpenthusiast.com/object-oriented-php-tutorials